# Examine whether the graphs are isomorphic

Tags: graph-theory, graph-isomorphism

I need to examine whether the graphs are isomorphic. It is clear that they have the same number of vertices, edges and degree sequence of both the graphs is the same I guess. But again I'm not sure if they are isomorphic.

[image: Graphs]

Answer (score 4):

It should be clear they are not.  The one on the left has cycles of length $3$.  The one on the right is bipartite and has no odd-length cycles.

Comment: +1 for a clear and concise argument; -1 for "it should be clear".